# Vários Schemas em um Owner no Oracle

Tags: oracle

Olá,

Estou com uma dúvida a um tempo e não acho uma resposta definitiva: Posso ter vários schemas em um owner do oracle?

Ex.:

Owner: Renan

Schemas:

1. Indicadores
2. Alerta
3. Etc

Tabelas:

1. renan.Indicadores.tb_rend_acum_teste
2. renan.Alerta.tb_voo
3. renan.etc.teste

No SQL SERVER funciona assim e gostaria de saber se consigo fazer a mesma coisa no oracle.

Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O ORACLE funciona diferente. Ao criar um usuário já é associado um schema a ele com o mesmo nome.

Aqui segue um explicação sobre isso: [http://oraclemais.blogspot.com.br/2008/10/o-que-um-schema.html]

Comment: Vou ter que criar diversos usuários então. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Não. Cada usuário tem o seu próprio schema que são todos os seus objetos no banco, desde tabelas, a views, sinônimos e etc.